# IF logic on Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What is the obvious error in this formula?  I am trying to compare if Billing Codes are used in particular fields and in my case, I am testing to see if all the billing codes were used.

```
=IF(C6:L6 = P5 and P7 and P8 and P9 and P10 and P11 and P12 and P13 and P14 and P15, 1, 2)
```

Comment: `P5 and P7 and P8 and P9 and P10 and P11 and P12 and P13 and P14 and P15` is invalid. Could you give some values of what you're trying to do? Like, in C6, there is 1, D6, there's 2, etc. Since 2, 6 are in cells P5 (or something), then it should return 1. Otherwise, it'll take a whole night to get to what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can't combine the ands that way, nor do logic on a range. It is unclear to Excel and to us what you would like to happen. Seems like maybe you want to make sure all the P values are found somewhere in the C:L values?

Comment: I need to test to see if cells C6:L6 use all of these codes...CMMTS,
CW,CWL,DC,INBOX,NCC,SP,TC,VR,NOTE,TR and OC.

Comment: Yes, there can be duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have understood from your post, is this what you are trying?

`=IF((COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,C6) + COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,D6) + COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,E6) + COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,F6) + COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,G6) + COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,H6) + COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,I6) + COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,J6) + COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,K6) + COUNTIF($P$5:$P$16,L6)) = 10,1,2)`

[image]

Comment: Oh a shot in the dark worked :p